# Is UWP compatible with CosmosDb

Tags: c#, uwp, azure-cosmosdb

I have a .net standard 2.0 class library. I am using a UWP front end with prism mvvm framework. When I  try to access cosmosdb in my view model the document client does not return. Is there a compatability issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on our exist project, no compatability issue.

For policy limit, I can share our code. But I found an 3rd link for your reference:

> https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/customized-azure-cosmos-db-with-xamarin-forms-application-student-detail-for-a/

Summary for the reference:

> 1. Creating Azure Cosmos DB.
> 2. Create an Xamarin.Forms app:  Open Visual Studio 2017 -> Start -> New Project-> Select Cross-Platform (under Visual C#->Cross Platform
>      ->Mobile App(Xamarin.Forms)-> Give a Suitable Name for your App (XamFormStudCos) ->OK.
>
> Select the Cross Platform template as Blank APP ->Set Platform as
>   Android, iOS and UWP and code sharing strategy as Shared Project.
>
> Add the Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core Reference.
>
> Add Connection.cs class for xamstudcosmos Account (CosmosDB):
>
> ```
> using Newtonsoft.Json;  
> public class Connection {  
>     public static readonly string EndpointUri = "https://xamstudcosmos.documents.azure.com:443/";  
>     public static readonly string PrimaryKey = "r03kRnNeyU3Bij7b9TZgsrkoKoU2ERdWM2d2jMAaaKWFClSJobyC8SyXmeazwKEwm8c2UhEjCNDU9NhI4grEFQ==";
>
>     public static readonly string DatabaseName = "StudentDB";  
>     public static readonly string CollectionName = "Student";  
> }
> ```
>
> Using MVC, first Create Model Folder and Add the StudentDetail Class
>   for data Model:
>
> ```
> public class StudentDetail {  
>     [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]  
>     public string Id {  
>         get;  
>         set;  
>     }  
>     [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]  
>     public string Name {  
>         get;  
>         set;  
>     }  
>     [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Age")]  
>     public string Age {  
>         get;  
>         set;  
>     }  
> }
> ```
>
> Create Controller Folder and Add the IDocumentDBService Interface for DocumentDB:
>
> ```
> using System.Threading.Tasks;  
> using XamFormStudCos.Model;  
> public interface IDocumentDBService {  
>     Task CreateDatabaseAsync(string databaseName);  
>     Task CreateDocumentCollectionAsync(string databaseName, string collectionName);  
>     Task < List < StudentDetail >> GetStoreInfoAsync();  
>     Task SaveStudentDetailAsync(StudentDetail stud, bool isNewstudent);  
>     Task DeleteStudentAsync(string id);  
> }
> ```
>
> Add the DocumentDBService Class for implementing IDocumentDBService
>   interface
>
> ```
> using System.Threading.Tasks;  
> using XamFormStudCos.Model;  
> using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;  
> using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;  
> using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq;  
> using System.Diagnostics;  
> class DocumentDBService: IDocumentDBService {  
>     public List < StudentDetail > Items {  
>         get;  
>         private set;  
>     }  
>     DocumentClient client;  
>     Uri collectionLink;  
>     public DocumentDBService() {  
>         client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(Connection.EndpointUri), Connection.PrimaryKey);  
>
> collectionLink = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(Connection.DatabaseName,
> ```
>
> Connection.CollectionName);   }   public async Task
>   CreateDatabaseAsync(string databaseName) {
>       try {
>           await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(new Database {
>               Id = databaseName
>           });
>       } catch (DocumentClientException ex) {
>           Debug.WriteLine("Error: ", ex.Message);
>       }   }   public async Task CreateDocumentCollectionAsync(string databaseName, string collectionName) {
>       try {
>           await client.CreateDocumentCollectionIfNotExistsAsync(UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(Connection.DatabaseName),
>   new DocumentCollection {
>               Id = collectionName
>           }, new RequestOptions {
>               OfferThroughput = 400
>           });
>       } catch (DocumentClientException ex) {
>           Debug.WriteLine("Error: ", ex.Message);
>       }   }   public async Task DeleteStudentAsync(string id) {
>       try {
>           await client.DeleteDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(Connection.DatabaseName,
>   Connection.CollectionName, id));
>
> ```
>         } catch (DocumentClientException ex) {  
>             Debug.WriteLine("Error: ", ex.Message);  
>         }  
>     }  
>     async Task DeleteDocumentCollection() {  
>         try {  
>             await client.DeleteDocumentCollectionAsync(collectionLink);  
>         } catch (DocumentClientException ex) {  
>             Debug.WriteLine("Error: ", ex.Message);  
>         }  
>     }  
>     async Task DeleteDatabase() {  
>         try {  
>             await client.DeleteDatabaseAsync(UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(Connection.DatabaseName));
>
>         } catch (DocumentClientException ex) {  
>             Debug.WriteLine("Error: ", ex.Message);  
>         }  
>     }  
>     public async Task < List < StudentDetail >> GetStudentAsync() {  
>         Items = new List < StudentDetail > ();  
>         try {  
>             var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery < StudentDetail > (collectionLink).AsDocumentQuery();  
>             while (query.HasMoreResults) {  
>                 Items.AddRange(await query.ExecuteNextAsync < StudentDetail > ());
>
>             }  
>         } catch (DocumentClientException ex) {  
>             Debug.WriteLine("Error: ", ex.Message);  
>         }  
>         return Items;  
>     }  
>     public async Task SaveStudentDetailAsync(StudentDetail student, bool isNewItem) {  
>         try {  
>             if (isNewItem) {  
>                 await client.CreateDocumentAsync(collectionLink, student);  
>             } else {  
>                 await client.ReplaceDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(Connection.DatabaseName,
> ```
>
> Connection.CollectionName, student.Id), student);
>                   }
>               } catch (DocumentClientException ex) {
>                   Debug.WriteLine("Error: ", ex.Message);
>               }
>           }
>       } 
>   Add the StudentDetailManager Class.
>
> ```
> using System.Threading.Tasks;  
> using XamFormStudCos.Model;  
> using XamFormStudCos.Controller;  
> public class StudentDetailManager {  
>     IDocumentDBService documentDBService;  
>     public StudentDetailManager(IDocumentDBService service) {  
>         documentDBService = service;  
>     }  
>     public Task CreateDatabase(string databaseName) {  
>         return documentDBService.CreateDatabaseAsync(databaseName);  
>     }  
>     public Task CreateDocumentCollection(string databaseName, string collectionName) {  
>         return documentDBService.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync(databaseName,
> ```
>
> collectionName);
>           }
>           public Task < List < StudentDetail >> GetStoreInfoAsync() {
>               return documentDBService.GetStoreInfoAsync();
>           }
>           public Task SaveStudentDetailAsync(StudentDetail student, bool isNewItem = false) {
>               return documentDBService.SaveStudentDetailAsync(student, isNewItem);
>           }
>           public Task DeleteStudentAsync(StudentDetail student) {
>               return documentDBService.DeleteStudentAsync(student.Id);
>           }
>       }
>   Add the following Namespaces and code in App.xaml.cs.
>
> ```
> using XamFormStudCos.Controller;  
> using XamFormStudCos.View;  
> public static StudentDetailManager StudentDetailManager {  
>     get;  
>     private set;  
> }  
> public App() {  
>     InitializeComponent();  
>     StudentDetailManager = new StudentDetailManager(new DocumentDBService());  
>     MainPage = new NavigationPage(new StudentList());  
> }
> ```
>
> Next, Create View Folder and Add the StudentList Xaml Page for Viewing all student lists. Add Toolbar item with Add and ListView item
>   for Viewing student list.
>
> ```
> <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>  
>     <ToolbarItem Text="Add" Order="Primary" Clicked="OnItemAdded" /> </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>  
> <ListView x:Name="SList" ItemSelected="OnItemselected">  
>     <ListView.ItemTemplate>  
>         <DataTemplate>  
>             <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" Detail="{Binding Age}" /> </DataTemplate>  
>     </ListView.ItemTemplate>  
> </ListView>
> ```
>
> Add the following Namespaces and code in StudentList.xaml.cs
>
> ```
> using XamFormStudCos.Model;  
> protected override async void OnAppearing() {  
>     base.OnAppearing();  
>     await App.StudentDetailManager.CreateDatabase(Constants.DatabaseName);  
>     await App.StudentDetailManager.CreateDocumentCollection(Constants.DatabaseName,
> ```
>
> Constants.CollectionName);
>           var data = await App.StudentDetailManager.GetStoreInfoAsync();
>           StdList.ItemsSource = data;
>       }
>       async void OnItemAdded(object sender, EventArgs e) {
>           await Navigation.PushAsync(new StudentDetails(true) {
>               BindingContext = new StudentDetail {
>                   Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
>               }
>           });
>       }
>       async void OnItemselected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e) {
>           if (e.SelectedItem != null) {
>               await Navigation.PushAsync(new EditStudent() {
>                   BindingContext = e.SelectedItem as StudentDetail
>               });
>           }
>       }
>
> Add the StudentDetails Xaml Page for adding New Student Detail.
>
> For adding a new student, Add Label, Entry, and Button controls with
>   click event method.
>
> ```
> <ContentPage.Content>  
>     <StackLayout Margin="20" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">  
>         <Label Text="Name" />  
>         <Entry Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Placeholder="Enter Student Name" />  
>         <Label Text="Age" />  
>         <Entry Text="{Binding Path=Age}" />  
>         <Button Text="Save" Clicked="OnSaveClicked" />  
>         <Button Text="Cancel" Clicked="OnCancelClicked" /> </StackLayout>  
> </ContentPage.Content>
> ```
>
> Add the following Namespaces and code in StudentDetail.xaml.cs
>
> ```
> using XamFormStudCos.Model;  
> bool isNewItem;  
> public StudentDetails(bool isNew) {  
>     InitializeComponent();  
>     isNewItem = isNew;  
> }  
> async void OnSaveClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {  
>     var student = (StudentDetail) BindingContext;  
>     await App.StudentDetailManager.SaveStudentDetailAsync(student, isNewItem);  
>     await Navigation.PopAsync();  
> }  
> async void OnCancelClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {  
>     await Navigation.PopAsync();  
> }
> ```
>
> Add the EditStudent Xaml Page for EditStudent (Update, Delete) Detail.
>
> For Editing a student, Add Label, Entry and Button controls with click
>   event method,
>
> ```
> <StackLayout Padding="10" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">  
>     <Grid>  
>         <Label Text="Name" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" WidthRequest="100" VerticalOptions="Center"
> ```
>
> />
>
> ```
>     <Button Text="Cancel" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Blue" TextColor="White" Clicked="OnCancelClicked" />
> ```
>
> Add the following Namespaces and code in EditStudent.xaml.cs
>
> ```
> using XamFormStudCos.Model;  
> async void Update_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {  
>     var student = (StudentDetail) BindingContext;  
>     await App.StudentDetailManager.SaveStudentDetailAsync(student);  
>     await Navigation.PopAsync();  
> }  
> async void OnDeleteClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {  
>     bool accepted = await DisplayAlert("Confirm", "Are you Sure ?", "Yes", "No");  
>     if (accepted) {  
>         var student = (StudentDetail) BindingContext;  
>         await App.StudentDetailManager.DeleteStudentAsync(student);  
>         await Navigation.PopAsync();  
>     }  
> }  
> async void OnCancelClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {  
>     await Navigation.PopAsync();  
> }
> ```
>
> Build and Deploy.

You need to check your config or other code logic.

Comment: Please provide a summary of the linked content. In case the off-site resource becomes unavailable, this answer needs to keep being useful. The only way to maintain that is by posting the relevant information here, and keep the link as a reference only.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft support said that Cosmos DB will not work (and has never worked) on UWP in Release mode (and it's a low priority to fix it).  I'm assuming this example was only run in Debug mode.  I would love to know of a workaround.  I've tried both V2 SDK and V3 SDK.
Nothing as complicated as this example is needed to repro. Just start with the Blank UWP app template and try to query Cosmos.